# Send Notifications from code Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

i am making an application that uses Firebase as the backend and swift in xcode. What i have is i can add products to the database and users can view and see those products. But what i want to do is that whenever i add a new product i want to send notifications to all registered users. How can i achieve that? I have seen tutorials and Firebase's own documentation but all these send notifications via Firebase console. How can i achieve this through swift code? I am using Swift 3.0 and xcode 8.3.2. Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: This forum is really for helping with coding specific questions. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That being said, to understand how you go about addressing the task in your question, start with a simple Firebase project using the Firebase Database. Once you understand that, your question will answer itself. You can accomplish everything you need through Firebase Observers... but you can expand on that with Cloud Functions and Notifications. See [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

Comment: Firebase observers will not respond when the app is not running. I want it to receive notifications even when it is quit or not running.

Comment: There is no API for sending messages to an Audiences. Sending notifications from code is done with Firebase Cloud Messaging. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/. You will need a trusted process to run the code though, you can't directly push messages from one device to another. See this blog for an example of doing so for Android: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So can i send notification through a trusted server using FCM to different devices when a new product is added?

Comment: Sure. For another example, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: You could also make users sign up for a service like OneSignal, and from there send a notification to the audience

Comment: @GlennHerping Can you show me how to do that? Maybe a little piece of code or a tutorial?

Comment: Follow the steps on the following link. Remember you must have an active developer account to create a push certificate. 
[OneSignal Docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup)